# How to efficiently delete old Firebase Cloud documents using a Google Cloud Function?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am currently using the following scheduled Cloud Function to delete any Assignments or Duties (documents) older than 24 hours. The function works fine, and the documents successfully delete.

However a HUGE amount of **Reads** are being reported by the function. It seems that *every single* assignment or duty is being "read", regardless of whether it needs to be deleted or not. It was my understanding that queries do count as reading, unless they return a document in the querySnapshot that is used? E.G. Any documents do be deleted will have a READ and DELETE.

Does anyone know how to optimize this to only read documents that must be deleted? Or is there an easier way to delete old Cloud Firebase documents using a Google Cloud Function? I would have thought this is a really common thing to do.

*** UPDATED #2 with collectionGroup and correct use of Promises (Thanks for your help!) ***

Same problem: When the function is run, it is showing 844 Reads and 1 Delete. There is definitely no other sources reading the data. The spikes only occur right after running the function (using Google Cloud Scheduler - Run Now)

Interestingly, if there are NO documents to delete, then there are NO reads recorded. But if there is > 1 document to delete, there are hundreds of Reads. Currently there are only about 120 Duties in the whole collection! It seems each duty is being read multiple times!?

[image: Reads Spike right after the function runs]

[image]

Thanks!

```
exports.scheduledCleanOldDutiesCollection = functions.pubsub.schedule('0 3 * * *')
    .timeZone('America/Chicago')
    .onRun((context) => {
        const dateYesterday = new Date(new Date().getTime() - (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));   // 24 hours
        return db.collectionGroup('duties').where('date', '<', dateYesterday).get()
            .then(querySnapshot => {
                const promises = [];
                querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
                    promises.push(doc.ref.delete());
                });
                return Promise.all(promises);
            });
    });
```

Comment: A few questions: 1) What exactly are you observing that measure your reads? 2) Do you realize that your function is unconditionally reading every single document in "companies" on every execution? You didn't seem to mention this fact in your text. That could be costly.  3) **You are not dealing with promises correctly on your inner reads and deletes.** In fact, you are ignoring a lot of promises.  This is the big one.  Your code should return a promise that resolves only after all the async work is complete, else it will get terminated early.

Comment: To be clear, I am suggesting that you could be paying for lots of document reads that don't result in deletes because the function got terminated before the deletes happened.

Comment: Hi Doug, Thanks for your message. 1) Cloud Firestore Monitoring and Cloud Database Usage. I have real-time monitoring, and after running the function manually observe the usage. 2) Yes, but currently there are only 2 companies and 100s of assignments. I'm not sure how to avoid reading the "companies" and achieve the same thing. 3) I understand what you're saying, but don't know how to "deal with" a promise without "returning". Then I can't process the 2nd list...?

Comment: I suggest doing some searches for how to use promises effectively in a foreach loop. You will need to learn how to use `Promise.all()`, or learn async/await syntax, or optimally both.

Comment: OK, I've adjusted the code to use collectionGroups, which removes the Promises issues. The main issue is the reads. Nearly 1000 reads for 1 delete.

Comment: You're still not handling promises correctly.  Just calling `then` or `catch` on a promise doesn't make the entire function wait for it to complete.

Comment: Thanks, this has now been updated. The same problem persists, huge Reads for a small number of deletions.

Comment: If you print the size of the query results in the function, and it doesn't match what you see in the console, then you should contact Firebase support directly.  There's not much we can do to help if they are not in parity.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Answer (score 4):

As Doug explained in his comment and in the official [video series](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/video-series), your code must return a promise that resolves only after all the asynchronous work is complete, else the Cloud Function will get terminated early.

You can adapt your code as follows, by using [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all):

```
exports.scheduledCleanOldDutiesCollection = functions.pubsub.schedule('0 3 * * *')
    .timeZone('America/Chicago')
    .onRun((context) => {
        const dateYesterday = new Date(new Date().getTime() - (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));   // 24 hours
        return db.collectionGroup('duties').where('date', '<', dateYesterday).get()
            .then(querySnapshot => {
                const promises = [];
                querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
                    promises.push(doc.ref.delete());
                });
                return Promise.all(promises);
            });
    });
```

Comment: Hi Renaud, Thanks for that, I really appreciate the help. I have changed the code exactly as you've shown. The function works fine, but the same problem remains, when the function runs it reports 844 Reads and 1 Delete. I'll update the question... Any ideas?

Comment: Hi @Damian, I cannot add much to what Doug said in his latest comment. You can get the size of the `querySnapshot` by doing `.then(querySnapshot => { console.log(querySnapshot.size); ....`.